# Difference between isObservable and isSubscribable

Tags: knockout.js

Seems they return the same result, why use one over the other?

```
var computed = ko.computed(function(){return 'foo';});
var observable  = ko.observable();
var observableArray  = ko.observableArray();

console.log('computed isObservable', ko.isObservable(computed));
console.log('observable isObservable', ko.isObservable(observable));
console.log('observableArray isObservable', ko.isObservable(observableArray));

console.log('computed isSubscribable', ko.isSubscribable(computed));
console.log('observable isSubscribable', ko.isSubscribable(observable));
console.log('observableArray isSubscribable', ko.isSubscribable(observableArray));
```

All log true.
http://jsfiddle.net/1fvjuj9v/1/

Comment: isSubscribable is not built in, its part of a pub/sub plugin

Comment: No, `ko.isSubscribable` is definitely part of KO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So a subscribable is a knockout object, different from observables or computeds, but that both observables and computeds inherit from.  A subscribable is anything that can be subscribed to; anything that can emit events which other parts of the code can listen to.  It's where the `observable.subscribe(function() {})` functionality is derived from.

An observable, on the other hand, is a specific type of a subscribable: it's a subscribable that holds a value and that emits the new value to its subscribers whenever that value changes.  The "has a current value" part of the observable isn't an inherent part of being a "subscribable", only the "emits events to its subscribers" part is.

It's not used much, but you *can* construct subscribables directly, and they will pass the `ko.isSubscribable` test but fail the `ko.isObservable` test, hence the difference between those two methods.

Though I personally haven't seen it done in practice, [this blog post](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html) gives an example of how you might make use of or extend the `ko.subscribable` functionality, by building a Pub/Sub interface on top of subscribables.

The relation is illustrated by this chart from the [knockout documentation on custom functions](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/fn.html).
[image: Chart displaying the relation between]

---

Note, however, that the above chart is a bit deceptive on one point: `ko.computed` actually derives from `ko.observable` not from `ko.subscribable` directly.  Hence why `ko.isObservable(computed)` returns true.  However the relation indicated by the chart *is* the relation used for inheriting custom functions added to knockout objects.  (Which makes sense, given that was the topic of the page of the documentation it was found on)

So if you define a custom function on `ko.subscribable.fn`, then it will be available both on computeds and on observables... but if you define one on `ko.observable.fn` it'll only be available on observables (and observable arrays) not on computeds, despite the fact that `ko.isObservable(computed)` returns true.

Comment: "It's not used much, but you can construct subscribables directly, and they will pass the ko.isSubscribable test but fail the ko.isObservable test, hence the difference between those two methods." This was what I was looking for , thanks!

Comment: Weird that they let isObservable return true for computeds imo. I like the separation depicted in the image better. And then rather use isSubscribable if you just want to know if you can subscribe to the value or not.

Comment: Yeah, the inconsistency is odd.  Though I think I prefer the actual inheritance better than the one from the chart.  If you think of observables as "subscribables with values" then computeds *are* observables; just a specific type, one that depends on other observables.  They have the same interface as observables (except that they can be read-only).